# How to display a date where there is no value for that date

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have a main table ( TMS ) that holds the date and time an emploiee has clocked on to the plant for the day,  joined to this I have derrived tables, one of which contains the time spent working on a task. for each day clocked in I can see the time they spent working on a task. I have an instant where the user might not clock on to the plant, but book time to a task. In my output Matrix becasue there is not a record of them attending site it will not show the time they booked to a task. Is there a way to show every date in the TMS table regardless if they have booked ?

I created a new Table that showed every date from 01-01-19 to 01-01-25, in the hope that when I joined the above tables I got "null" for any date we did not clock in or book time to a task.When I join this to  the above sets I still dont get a date where no clocking in took place.

Coding copied out of the SQL box from SSRS 2017 ( I tend to use the Grid pane for my coding  rather then typing the SQL ):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         WOL_TMS_INFO.ORG_UNIT, WOL_TMS_INFO.SAP_NO, format(WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE, 'MM') AS MONTH_PARAM, WOL_TMS_INFO.SITE, WOL_TMS_INFO.FIRSTNAME, WOL_TMS_INFO.SURNAME, 
                         YEAR(WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE) AS YEAR, WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE, WOL_TMS_INFO.HOURS_ATT, format(WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE, 'ddd') AS DATE1, WOL_TMS_INFO.PAID_ABSENCES, WOL_TMS_INFO.HOLIDAY, 
                         WOL_TMS_INFO.HOURS_SICK, HOURS_CUST_PAID_CERV_TBL.HOURS_CUST_PAID, ZPEFF_NP_TIME.NP_WORKING_TIME, CASE WHEN WORKING_TIME IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE WORKING_TIME END AS WORKING_TIME
FROM            WOL_TMS_INFO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT PERS_NO, PLNT, POSTG_DATE, SUM(WORKING_TIME + CASE WHEN UNIT = 'MIN' THEN ACTUAL_WORK / 60 ELSE ACTUAL_WORK END) AS WORKING_TIME
                               FROM            WOL_ZPEFF_DETAIL
                               GROUP BY PERS_NO, PLNT, POSTG_DATE
                               ORDER BY POSTG_DATE) AS zpeff_derv_tbl_working_time ON WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE = zpeff_derv_tbl_working_time.POSTG_DATE AND WOL_TMS_INFO.SAP_NO = zpeff_derv_tbl_working_time.PERS_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT PERS_NO, PLNT, POSTG_DATE, SUM(WORKING_TIME) AS NP_WORKING_TIME
                               FROM            (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT PERS_NO, PLNT, POSTG_DATE, SUM(WORKING_TIME + ACTUAL_WORK / 60) AS WORKING_TIME, REASON_FOR
                                                         FROM            WOL_ZPEFF_DETAIL AS WOL_ZPEFF_DETAIL_1
                                                         GROUP BY PERS_NO, PLNT, POSTG_DATE, REASON_FOR
                                                         HAVING         (REASON_FOR IS NOT NULL)
                                                         ORDER BY POSTG_DATE) AS ZPEFF_DERV_DERV_TBL
                               GROUP BY PERS_NO, PLNT, POSTG_DATE
                               ORDER BY POSTG_DATE) AS ZPEFF_NP_TIME ON WOL_TMS_INFO.SAP_NO = ZPEFF_NP_TIME.PERS_NO AND WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE = ZPEFF_NP_TIME.POSTG_DATE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT SAP_NO, DATE, SUM(HOURS_CUST_PAID) AS HOURS_CUST_PAID
                               FROM            WOL_TMS_INFO AS WOL_TMS_INFO_1
                               GROUP BY SAP_NO, DATE
                               ORDER BY DATE) AS HOURS_CUST_PAID_CERV_TBL ON WOL_TMS_INFO.SAP_NO = HOURS_CUST_PAID_CERV_TBL.SAP_NO AND WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE = HOURS_CUST_PAID_CERV_TBL.DATE
WHERE        (WOL_TMS_INFO.ORG_UNIT IN (@PROD_TEAM_PARAM)) AND (WOL_TMS_INFO.SAP_NO IN (@SAP_NO)) AND (format(WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE, 'MM') IN (@MONTH_PARAM)) AND (WOL_TMS_INFO.SITE = 'wolverton') AND 
                         (WOL_TMS_INFO.DATE > '01/01/2019')
ORDER BY MONTH_PARAM, WOL_TMS_INFO.SAP_NO
```

The Matrix works apart from not showing time booked where no time is attended to site

Answer (score 0):

You might try as part of your selection.  It should give you the clock into the plant time, but if that is null, then the time booked to the task.

Pseudo Code

```
ISNULL(ClockInPlantTime,BookToTaskTime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce, this would mean the booked to task time would show in my matrix under the clock in plant time which would skew the results. Its getting closer to what I want, I would just want the date to show but Zero in the attended to site time. I cannot work out how to post a picture on here so I can show the output ?  Tony